# Array insertion to SQL and retrieval formatting

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am working on sending a collection of custom objects to SQL. My objects look like this:

```
aa                              : True
phone_number                    :
manual_scan_time                : 0
ip_addr                         : 10.50.0.147
last_logon_user_guid            : 286c1410eb470e4ea31dd17e9c1eee31
urlfilter_violated              : 0
last_connect_time               : 1563379779
id                              : 0542c82cada09040be79bfb6e54fd119
spyware_detected                : 0
arch                            : x64
sched_start_time                : 1562922019
virus_detected                  : 0
platform                        : Win Server 2012 R2
version                         : 6.6.2457/14.1.1516
manual_aggressive_complete_time : 0
online                          : True
type                            : 1
status                          : 1
spam_detected                   : 0
sched_complete_time             : 1562926028
sched_scan_time                 : 1559294629
pop3_scan                       : False
manual_aggressive_start_time    : 0
last_logon_user_account         : jdoe
name                            : server01
ss_service                      : True
scan_mode                       : 0
manual_complete_time            : 0
mac_addr                        : 2B:41:38:B4:34:46
components                      : {@{version=0; type=1}, @{version=11.000.1006; type=3}, @{version=15.239.00; type=14}}
manual_start_time               : 0
last_logon_user_domain          : acme
created_at                      : 1510519578
last_connect_time_human         : 7/17/2019 4:09:39 PM
CustomerName                    : Acme Corp
```

Looking at the "components" property, I see it is an array and is not being set in the database. So, I started looking into how I might convert that to a string, in such a way that I could extract it later and convert it back to this array.

I am looping through the objects like this:

```
$sqlValues = New-Object Collections.ArrayList
$allComputers.computers | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | ForEach-Object {
        $_.PsObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
            If ($_.Value -match "'") {
                $_.Value = $_.Value.Replace("'", "''")
            }
        }
    }

    $sqlValues.Add("('$($_.aa)', '$($_.phone_number)', '$($_.manual_scan_time)', '$($_.ip_addr)', '$($_.last_logon_user_guid)', '$($_.urlfilter_violated)', '$($_.last_connect_time)', '$($_.id)', '$($_.spyware_detected)', '$($_.arch)', '$($_.sched_start_time)', '$($_.virus_detected)', '$($_.platform)', '$($_.version)', '$($_.manual_aggressive_complete_time)', '$($_.online)', '$($_.type)', '$($_.status)', '$($_.spam_detected)', '$($_.sched_complete_time)', '$($_.sched_scan_time)', '$($_.pop3_scan)', '$($_.manual_aggressive_start_time)', '$($_.last_logon_user_account)', '$($_.name)', '$($_.ss_service)', '$($_.scan_mode)', '$($_.manual_complete_time)', '$($_.mac_addr)', '$($_.components)', '$($_.manual_start_time)', '$($_.last_logon_user_domain)', '$($_.created_at)', '$($_.last_connect_time_human)', '$($_.CustomerName)', '$(Get-Date)')")
}
```

My first thought was to use:

```
$sqlValues.Add("('$($_.components | Out-String)'")
```

That worked, but the field was a string that looked like a table. Then I thought:

```
$sqlValues.Add("('$($($_.components | ForEach-Object {$_ -join ','}).TrimEnd())')")
```

That output looked right, but when I queried SQL to get the objects back, there are extra lines after "components" and "QueryDate". Where are those coming from? Or rather, how do I get rid of them?

```
aa                              : True
phone_number                    :
manual_scan_time                : 0
ip_addr                         : 10.50.0.147
last_logon_user_guid            : 286c1410eb470e4ea31dd17e9c1eee31
urlfilter_violated              : 0
last_connect_time               : 1563379779
id                              : 0542c82cada09040be79bfb6e54fd119
spyware_detected                : 0
arch                            : x64
sched_start_time                : 1562922019
virus_detected                  : 0
platform                        : Win Server 2012 R2
version                         : 6.6.2457/14.1.1516
manual_aggressive_complete_time : 0
online                          : True
type                            : 1
status                          : 1
spam_detected                   : 0
sched_complete_time             : 1562926028
sched_scan_time                 : 1559294629
pop3_scan                       : False
manual_aggressive_start_time    : 0
last_logon_user_account         : jdoe
name                            : server01
ss_service                      : True
scan_mode                       : 0
manual_complete_time            : 0
mac_addr                        : 2B:41:38:B4:34:46
components                      : @{version=0; type=1} @{version=11.000.1006; type=3} @{version=15.241.00; type=14}





manual_start_time               : 0
last_logon_user_domain          : acme
created_at                      : 1510519578
last_connect_time_human         : 7/17/2019 4:09:39 PM
CustomerName                    : Acme Corp

QueryDate                       : 7/18/2019 12:00:00 AM
```